# Virtual reality content capture in iOS and Swift

Tags: ios, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

I am looking into VR using Native swift, found some interesting ways to port google cardboard SDK but want to reach out and see if anyone has experience in this, specifically capturing panoramic images using an iPhone and converting them into VR content.

Comment: I don't think you need to port the SDK anymore, they released a version for iOS specifically on 3/30. Here's how to get started: https://developers.google.com/cardboard/ios/get-started

Comment: I am new to VR and don;t know if thats the best solution for content capture or are there other ways.